# C# service - OnStart() v Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm trying to understand the difference between `OnStart()` and the constructor in a `ServiceBase` derived class. From reading around it seems that the first time you start a service (after turning on your machine), the constructor is called. Thereafter, you can stop and start the service as many times as you like, but the constructor will never be called again, only the `OnStart()` method will be called each time. Can anyone confirm?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. And it's entirely logical.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do not use the constructor to perform processing that should be in `OnStart`. Use `OnStart` to handle all initialization of your service. The constructor is called when the application's executable runs, not when the service runs. The executable runs before `OnStart`. When you continue, for example, the constructor is not called again because the `SCM` already holds the object in memory. If `OnStop` releases resources allocated in the constructor rather than in `OnStart`, the needed resources would not be created again the second time the service is called.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to confirm I understood. Studying for my 70-536.

Comment: So if I have a service and need to, for example, initialize an event handler, I would want to do that in the onStart? Or no because it would initialize multiple instances on the handler?

Comment: if you subscribe to the event on the OnStart you should unsubcribe to the event in the OnStop.

Answer (score 5):

A slight variant is that it does depends on if it contains one service or multiple services. Here's the line from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.servicebase.aspx)

> If the executable contains a single
>   service, the system calls the
>   service's constructor when Start is
>   selected from the SCM, and runs the
>   destructor if Stop is called.
>
> If the executable contains multiple
>   services, calling Start on one service
>   causes the constructors to be called
>   for all services in the executable,
>   but only the specified service is
>   started. Destructors for the services
>   are run together when all services
>   have been stopped, not individually
>   when each service is stopped.

But oxilumin's answer probably is what you're after.

Comment: I think it should be the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is correct.  The constructor is called once per load and the on start can happen when a user (or automation) starts and stops the service.